# Torch, testing issue - imagenet-multiGPU.torch

Tags: machine-learning, torch

I am a newbies to torch. I have trainined my model according to 2 classes via this instruction https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch (number of classes is modifed) then, I wantted to test my model. These lines of codes are writen in instruction for testing:

```
dofile('donkey.lua')
img = testHook({loadSize}, 'test.jpg')
model = torch.load('model_10.t7')
if img:dim() == 3 then
   img = img:view(1, img:size(1), img:size(2), img:size(3))
end
predictions = model:forward(img:cuda())
```

I got errors at the initial line of codes while I was trying to write.
When I try to write ;

```
th> dofile('donkey.lua')
```

I get these errors;

```
th> dofile("donkey.lua")
donkey.lua:18: attempt to index global 'opt' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    donkey.lua:18: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    [string "_RESULT={dofile("donkey.lua")}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/leo/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651: in function 'repl'
    ...leo/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I don't know what to do. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `opts.lua` before running `donkey.lua` using

```
th> dofile("opts.lua")
```

Check `main.lua` and make sure, you are not missing any other dependencies.